# Can acceptable type be restricted for a generic method in java?

Tags: java, generics

I have a similar requirement to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/22780873/107301).
I would like to generify a method but restrict the types the acceptable by the generic parameter. Currently what I do is attempt to cast to the acceptable types in the method but seems cumbersome if dealing with more than 2 or 3 types.
**EDIT**:
The types may not be of the same base class. Apologies for not mentioning this earlier.

Comment: sure ... <T extends Number> means it can be any type, as long as it is an instance of Number (or a subclass there of)

Comment: @Stultuske I guess I should have mentioned that the types may not have the same class

Comment: T extends Number, U extends Person ..

Comment: While there exists the posibility for a generic type to be bounded by one class or interface and optionally by more interfaces at the same time (i.e. type1 AND type 2), there's no way to enforce that a generic type can be of either type1 OR type2. This doesn't make sense either, how would you know which method to call on the object of the generic type? There might exist workarounds for your problem, but you should be more specific and describe your use case better.

Answer (score 1):

For this, You must have a base class so that you can do this.

```
public class Person {
  String name;
  List<Profession> professions;
  int age;
}

public class Doctor {
  String university;
  Boolean doctorate;
  public void work() {
       // do work
  }
}

public class Teacher {
  List<Grade> grades;
  float salary;
  public void work() {
       // do work
  }
}

public class Animal<T> {
    T type;
}
```

So, now if you want to write a method which is generic and applies to all, You can do something like this,

```
public void doSomething(Animal<T extends Person> human) {
  human.work();
}
```

If the class is not of type `Person`, it will show a compilation error.
**UPD1:**
In the case, all the classes do not have a common base class. There is some functionality that makes them unique. By this, we can consider them to have a common function, which we can and should add using an **interface**.
Let's look at some code,

```
public class Human implements Growable {
  public void grow() {
    // human grow code
  }
}

public class Plant implements Growable {
  public void grow() {
    // plant grow code
  }
}

public class Table {
  // does not grows
}

public class GrowService {
  public static void grow(Growable growable) {
     growable.grow();
  }
}

interface Growable {
  public void grow();
}
```

And by calling the below method, we can achieve this

```
// Works fine
GrowingService.grow(new Plant());
// throws compilation error
GrowingService.grow(new Table());
```

Comment: The possible types are not of the same base class

Comment: If this is the case, all these classes are having a common functionality. I would recommend to add an interface to all those. And then do the same thing as above, now using interface

Answer (score 0):

Java Generics allow basic wildcards such as `<T>` but also more specifics like

`<T extends Number>` which means any type T that is Number or a subclass of it or

`<T super Number>` which means T can be Number or any superclass of Number all the way up to Object.

Comment: Yeah, I should have mentioned that the types may not be of the same base class